# Comparing String using regionMatches instead of compareTo()

Tags: java, string, compareto

Comparing String using `regionMatches` instead of  `compareTo()`

Example code:

code

```
s1. regionMatches(0,s2,3,5);
```

- The first argument is the starting index of `s1`
- The second argument is the comparison `String`
- The third argument is the starting index in the comparison `string`
- The last argument is the number of the character to compare.

My question is, how can I compare two strings of different length? 
If `s1` length is 5 and `s2` length is 9.  What should I put in the last argument?

Comment: What are you trying to find out?

Comment: hint: use math.min with start_index + number_characters_to_compare, and the string's length to make sure you don't go out of bounds